# Parse xml in Python ( One correct way to do so) using xlml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I am getting a response using requests module in Python and the response is in form of xml. I want to parse it and get details out of each 'dt' tag. I am not able to do that using lxml.

Here is the xml response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <entry_list version="1.0">
        <entry id="harsh">
            <ew>harsh</ew><subj>MD-2</subj><hw>harsh</hw>
            <sound><wav>harsh001.wav</wav><wpr>!h@rsh</wpr></sound>
            <pr>ˈhärsh</pr>
            <fl>adjective</fl>
            <et>Middle English <it>harsk,</it> of Scandinavian origin; akin to Norwegian <it>harsk</it> harsh</et>
            <def>
                <date>14th century</date>
                <sn>1</sn>
                <dt>:having a coarse uneven surface that is rough or unpleasant to the touch</dt>
                <sn>2 a</sn>
                <dt>:causing a disagreeable or painful sensory reaction :<sx>irritating</sx></dt>
                <sn>b</sn>
                <dt>:physically discomforting :<sx>painful</sx></dt>
                <sn>3</sn>
                <dt>:unduly exacting :<sx>severe</sx></dt>
                <sn>4</sn>
                <dt>:lacking in aesthetic appeal or refinement :<sx>crude</sx></dt>
               <ss>rough</ss>
           </def>
           <uro><ure>harsh*ly</ure> <fl>adverb</fl></uro>
           <uro><ure>harsh*ness</ure> <fl>noun</fl></uro>
       </entry>
    </entry_list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to traverse down the hierarchy of the xml document.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

re = requests.get(url)
root = etree.fromstring(re.content)
print(root.xpath('//entry_list/entry/def/dt/text()'))
```

This will give text value for each 'dt' tag in the xml document.

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

# List with dt values
dt_elems = []

# Process xml getting elements by tag name 
xmldoc = minidom.parse('text.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('dt')

# Get the values
for i in itemlist:
    dt_elems.append(" ".join(t.nodeValue for t in i.childNodes if t.nodeType==t.TEXT_NODE))

# Print the list result
print dt_elems
```